# Does SSIS packages created in 2008/2014 version works on SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have few SSIS packages created in 2012/2014 sql server version working good on SQL server 2014 .Now I am planning to upgrade my server to 2017 .Does SSIS run smoothly after upgrade ? or Do I need to do anything else ?

Comment: Are you upgrading SQL server i.e ssms to 2017 right. Either ways, i would deploy those packages to test server if they are running in SSIS catalogue, etc. and check further. We can not deploy based on assumptions though.  There shouldn't be much deprecating features that could break packages, and its worth checking for any Script tasks used in those packages

Comment: We use file system deployment .

Comment: then,I would believe you wont have much problems with upgrading

Answer (score 0):

From my previous experience with this, yes it does work for MOST occasions. There are exceptions depending on how complicated the package is, in which case, I would recommend just updating your SSIS package using the Package Upgrade wizard which is part of the SQL Server Data Tools

The upgrade is pretty straight forward, just run SSDT, open the Integration project and choose the "Upgrade All Packages", you can find more in depth instruction on the [MS SQL Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/install-windows/upgrade-integration-services-packages-using-the-ssis-package-upgrade-wizard?view=sql-server-2017)